# Redirect to mobile website every time

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, web

I'm using the typical mobile website redirect script that I've seen all over, and it works great. I also have a link on my mobile site that lets them view the regular website if desired, and that works as well.

Here's my scenario & problem. They go to my mobile website, then click the link to go to the regular website. Then they go visit a totally different site. If they type my url again to go to my website, it takes them to the regular website not the mobile site. Each separate time they go to my site I want them to be taken to the mobile. Can someone who is better at this help me out?? Thanks!

Here's my script on the regular website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0) {
        document.cookie = "skipmobile=1";
    } else if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 699) && document.cookie.indexOf("skipmobile") == -1) {
        document.location = "m/";
}
```

And here's the link from my mobile site:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html?skipmobile=1">View Full Website</a>
```

Comment: Does it allow them into the regular site even after the browser has closed? Or is it just while they're in one browser session?

Comment: Even after the browser is closed. If I open a new window I still get taken to the regular website.

Comment: Ah, then it's because of the cookie. You're better off storing "skipmobile" as a session. The session will be killed when they close the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't want them to have to close the browser. Even if they go back to the site a second time in the same window I want them to go to the mobile site. This is for a client of mine and that's what they want.

Comment: Then what you need to do is kill the session or the cookie when they leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's breakdown your JavaScript code.

```
if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0) {
```

If the URL contains the string "skipmobile" then the condition `>= 0` is true. Notice that it does not really matter what the value is set to.  It is only looking for the existence of the string "skipmobile".  When that string is in the URL a cookie is being set `document.cookie = "skipmobile=1"`.  `indexOf` will return a `-1` if the string is not found.

```
else if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 699) && document.cookie.indexOf("skipmobile") == -1)
```

Let's break this down into pieces. First off, `||` means OR and `&&` means AND.  So `if document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/)` is using a regular expression to search the hostname from the URL for the string ".mobi" at the end. So www.yoursite.mobi would match but www.yoursite.com would not.  Then we have the OR condition `|| screen.width < 699`.  So if the hostname ends with ".mobi" OR if the screen dimension's width is less than "699" pixels the first part of this condition will be true.

The next part of this if statement is `document.cookie.indexOf("skipmobile") == -1`. This is checking for the non-existence of a cookie named "skipmobile". Notice the `-1`. So it is checking that the cookie has NOT been set.

So put that all together, if the hostname ends in ".mobi" **OR** the screen width is less than "699" pixels **AND** the cookie "skipmobile" has not been set then direct the browser to the mobile site, "m/", using this code `document.location = "m/"`.

It looks like the code is checking for the cookie to determine mobile or full site. Because of this it is "remembering" the setting when they leave and come back to your site.

Answer (score 0):

When setting your cookie - specifically do not set an expiry date.  This is commonly referred to as a "session cookie". The cookie will automatically expire when the browser is closed.

or better yet...

Quite simply, just don't set a cookie at all. I don't see anywhere in the code where the actual presence of a cookie does anything... only the absence of the cookie matters.

furthermore, if you don't set a cookie... there will never be a cookie. Why waste code looking for it?

Try this instead...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0)
{
document.location = "m/";
} else if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 699))
{
document.location = "m/";
}
</script>
```